# Unique Particle Attribution violation with choice and group

Tags: xml, validation, xsd

I have the following XSD:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    targetNamespace="http://www.example.org/MessageSchema" xmlns="http://www.example.org/MessageSchema"
    elementFormDefault="qualified">

  <xs:element name="message">       
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:choice>
                <xs:group ref="loginMessage"/>
                <xs:group ref="fooMessage"/>
            </xs:choice>
        </xs:complexType>   
    </xs:element>

  <xs:group name="loginMessage">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="operation" type="xs:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" fixed="Login"/>
            <xs:element name="login" type="loginType" />
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:group>

  <xs:group name="fooMessage">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="operation" type="xs:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" fixed="Foo"/>
            <xs:element name="foo" type="fooType" />
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:group>

  <xs:complexType name="loginType">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="token" type="xs:string" />
            <xs:element name="nickName" type="xs:string" />
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>

  <xs:complexType name="fooType">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="bar" type="xs:string" />
            <xs:element name="num" type="xs:integer" />
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>

</xs:schema>
```

I want to be able to have XML like the following examples:

```
<!--Example 1-->
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<mensaje xmlns="http://www.example.org/MessageSchema"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.example.org/MessageSchema MessageSchema.xsd">    
  <operation>Login</operation>  
  <login>
    <token>asda8987</token>
    <nickName>Test</nickName>
  </login>  
</mensaje>

<!--Example 2-->
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<mensaje xmlns="http://www.example.org/MessageSchema"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.example.org/MessageSchema MessageSchema.xsd">    
  <operation>Foo</operation>    
  <foo>        
    <bar>bar</bar>
    <num>100</num>
  </foo>    
</mensaje>
```

My aim is to force the operation element to have a fixed value depending on the message structure but I am getting a Unique Particle Attribution. I understand the ambiguity perfectly in the operation tag but in same time I am unable to find a way to force my structure restriction. I was expecting the validation not to fail due to the fact that the operation tag has a different fixed values and therefore should be distinguished.

Answer (score 0):

Disambiguation of elements considers only element name and namespace. Hence, as far as XSD validation is concerned, the two groups in your choice overlap (cf. https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-1/#non-ambig).

So, one solution is to give your operations different element names (`<fooOperation/>` and `<loginOperation/>` instead of `<operation>foo</operation>` and `<operation>login</operation>`).

Another solution, at least according to your structure so far, would be to change the element sequence in your groups, putting your distinguishing elements (foo, login) first and moving the operation element behind (or make it an attribute).

Third, if you want to stick to exactly the same syntax, you have to put the operation element out of the groups and before the choice. However, then you need some semantic constraint, which requires assertions (XML Schema 1.1) or Schematron, in order to connect the correct groups and operation values.